# Inequality for joint distribution function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, bivariate-distributions

The following problem is from Rohatgi 
Let (X,Y) have joint density function f and joint distribution function F. Suppose that
$f(x_1,y_1)f(x_2,y_2) \le f(x_1,y_2)f(x_2,y_1)$ holds for any $x_1 \le a \le x_2$ and $y_1 \le b \le y_2 $.
Show that
$F(a,b) \le F_1(a)F_2(b)$.

My attempt:

I tried writing it out from definition:
$$F(a,b) = P(X \le a, Y \le b) = \int_{-\infty}^a \int_{-\infty}^bf(x,y)dydx$$
but I'm not sure how to introduce the given inequality

Any hints?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^a\int_b^\infty f(x,y)dydx&=\int_{-\infty}^a\left[\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x,y)dy-\int_{-\infty}^bf(x,y)dy\right]dx\\
&=F_1(a)-F(a,b)\ ,\\
\int_a^\infty\int_{-\infty}^bf(x,y)dydx&=F_2(b)-F(a,b)\ \text{, and}\\
\int_a^\infty\int_{b}^\infty f\left(x,y\right)dydx&=1-F_1(a)-F_2(b)+F(a,b)\ ,
\end{align}
and integrating the inequality you're given over the ranges $\ -\infty < x_1\le a\ $, $\ -\infty < y_1\le b\ $, $\ a < x_2\le \infty\ $, and $\ b < y_2\le \infty\ $ gives
$$
\int_{-\infty}^a\int_{-\infty}^b f\left(x_1,y_1\right)dy_1dx_1\int_a^\infty\int_{b}^\infty f\left(x_2,y_2\right)dy_2dx_2\le\\
\int_{-\infty}^a\int_b^\infty f\left(x_1,y_2\right)dy_2dx_1\int_a^\infty\int_{-\infty}^bf\left(x_2,y_1\right)dy_1dx_2\ .
$$
Can you take it from there?